# How do I SQL inject a Java Statement that uses JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc, sql-injection

The following lines of code appear in my Java program:

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM metropolises WHERE metropolis =\"" + metropolis + "\" AND continent=\"" + continent + "\" AND population>" + population);
```

I can put anything in for metropolis, continent, and population via a GUI, but I can't seem to get it to work if I put metropolis = `a`, continent = `b`, and population is `2; DROP TABLE tablename;`

Any suggestions? I'm trying to DROP a table named metropolises so I can better understand SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Some database libraries don't allow to execute multiple queries per call (PHP's mysql binder for example). In those, this kind of injection is not possible. Unfortunately, I don't know whether this is true for JDBC, but it might be the reason.

Comment: JDBC is only an **API**, whether or not this is possible depends on the specific driver. It's not "true" or "false" for JDBC as such

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what brand of database you're using (unless the "sql" tag implies Microsoft SQL Server).  So here's my experience w.r.t. MySQL:

By default, the MySQL JDBC driver will execute only a single SQL statement per call.  This is a good idea for defending against some types of SQL injection.

The JDBC driver has an optional connection property `allowMultiQueries` that you must set to allow semicolon-separated statements.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html